# Django Form Not Adding to SQLite3 Database

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django form that is purposed to create a new item in my database. It is returning a 'false-positive' in that it shows a green 'Done' after I hit submit but the record is not actually added to the database. Any ideas what is causing this?

html

```
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form}}
                        <div style="color:green">{{info}}</div>
                        <div style="color:red">{{error}}</div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

views.py

```
def creator(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommunicationsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request,'polls/creation.html',{"form":CommunicationsForm,"info":"Done"})
    else:
        return render(request,'polls/creation.html',{"form":CommunicationsForm})
```

forms.py

```
class CommunicationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communications
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'project':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter your Project Name'}),
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter a short Title'}),
            'intent':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Describe the intent and desired outcome of the communication'}),
            'date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Date'}),
            'channel':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Channel'}),
            'content_type':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select a Content Type'}),
            'audience':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter the Audience(s)'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Select the Status'}),
            }
```

models.py

```
class Communications(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    intent = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    audience = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.communication
```

Comment: Even if `form.is_valid()` fails, you call `render(...)` with `{'info': 'Done'}`...

Comment: I was intending to write that as "if the form is valid, save the form, then print 'Done' for the user" - i'm assuming that is not what that logic says?

Comment: no, then you need to indent the `render` under the `if form.is_valid()` part. But nevertheless, that is still not a good idea: a successful POST normally means you respond with a redirect: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/rendering_content_after_a_successful_post_request.html